# What `type variables` means when they occurred in `val` declaration statement in SML

Tags: sml

In SML/NJ repl, the following expression is accepted:

```
- val 'a a = [];
val a = [] : 'a list
- val 'a a = 1;
val a = 1 : int
```

What's the `'a` means here? I don't know what effect will they made, and this is defined in the definition, but I can't find related description in *Programming in Standard ML*.

Please!

Comment: Variables vary over values: the variable "x", lets say has type int, it can have values 1, 2, 3, 4 or any other int. A type variable varies over types: 'a list is a type for lists with a yet unknown base type. They come into play when you want to have a function which doesn't care about the base type of an argument, for example for the length function it doesnt matter if it is calculating the length of and int list or char list. Whenever you see a type variable you can interpret it as it stands for any type...ie it helps to give a type to polymorphic functions.

Answer (score 3):

Type variables bound by `val` are only relevant when you use them. You can enforce (or restrict) polymorphism with them, e.g.

```
fun 'a pair (x : 'a, y : 'a) = (x, y)
```

which is short for

```
val 'a pair = fn (x : 'a, y : 'a) => (x, y)
```

You can write the same without putting an explicit `'a` at the beginning. However, the scoping rules then are rather tricky, especially when you use `'a` in several declarations. For example:

```
fun f () =
    let
        fun pair (x : 'a, y : 'a) = (x, y)
        fun triple (x : 'a, y : 'a, z : 'a) = (x, y, z)
    in
        ...
    end
```

What does this mean? There are at least two possible answers:

```
fun f () =
    let
        fun 'a pair (x : 'a, y : 'a) = (x, y)
        fun 'a triple (x : 'a, y : 'a, z : 'a) = (x, y, z)
    in
        ...
    end
```

or

```
fun 'a f () =
    let
        fun pair (x : 'a, y : 'a) = (x, y)
        fun triple (x : 'a, y : 'a, z : 'a) = (x, y, z)
    in
        ...
    end
```

In the former case, `pair` and `triple` would both be fully polymorphic inside a monomorphic `f`, in the latter, they would be monomorphic, relative to the instantiation of a (polymorphic) `f`!

The answer is that SML actually picks the latter interpretation: if you use a type variable in an annotation that has no explicit binding point, then its scope is the *smallest enclosing declaration that contains all occurrences of the same variable*.

Sometimes that's even what you want. But clearly, it's better to be able to be explicit about it, and not rely on tricky implicit scoping rules.

Comment: I've got the idea, Thanks a lot. BTW, could you please tell me where can I get systematic description for the polymorphic and monomorphic knowledge about SML? I don't have know how the compiler and type checker works. Thanks.